# Cannot convert from Expression<Func<T,bool>> to Expression<Func<User,bool>> when T = User within class

Tags: c#, linq, generics, type-conversion

So say I have this class and method, context of `Store.Users`. `Get` is of type `User`. However when i have the method parameter as `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` and pass that as the expression for the `Get()` method. I receive a IDE & build error stating:

```
Argument 1 : cannot convert from Expression<Func<T,bool>> to Expression<Func<User,bool>>.
'Argument Type: Expression<Func<T,bool>> is not assignable to parameter type Expression<Func<User,bool>>'.
```

Every other part of the code is able to pick up that `T` is of type `User`, apart from in this instance. Any tips / ideas would be great.

```
public class Builder<T> : DataBuilder<T> where T : User
{
   public override T Exists(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicateExpression)
    {
       return Store.Users.Get(predicateExpression).FirstOrDefault();            
    } 
}
```

Comment: The type of Store.Users.Get is strict, i.e. it NEEDS to be User. With the code you have, it can be something else, so the compiler won't allow it. The generic where constraint is telling the compiler it can be User or a class that inherits from User. Lets say you create SuperUser inherited from User, you would not be able to call Store.Users.Get with an Expression<Func<SuperUser, bool>>. Nevertheless, what you are doing is interesting. Good luck!

Comment: Why is `Builder` generic? Why not have `class Builder : DataBuilder<User>` ?

Comment: Instead of calling Store.Users.Get can you implement more generic access e.g. on  context.Set<T>().Get() ?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to modify the `Expression` to convert to the proper type with `as` - however, passing in the wrong type will cause a runtime exception and there is some slight overhead to doing this.

First, you need an `ExpressionVisitor` for replacing `Expression`s in an `Expression` (feels like something that should be built-in):

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces an Expression (reference Equals) with another Expression
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orig">The original Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="from">The from Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="to">The to Expression.</param>
    /// <returns>Expression with all occurrences of from replaced with to</returns>
    public static Expression Replace(this Expression orig, Expression from, Expression to) => new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(orig);

    /// <summary>
    /// ExpressionVisitor to replace an Expression (that is Equals) with another Expression.
    /// </summary>
    public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
        readonly Expression from;
        readonly Expression to;

        public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this to wrap the original `Expression` parameter with the appropriate `as`:

```
public class Builder<T> : DataBuilder<T> where T : User {
    public override T Exists(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicateExpression) {
        var p = predicateExpression.Parameters[0];
        var pAsUser = Expression.MakeUnary(ExpressionType.TypeAs, p, typeof(User));
        var b = predicateExpression.Body.Replace(p, pAsUser);
        var newpe = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(b, p);

        return (T)Store.Users.Get(newpe).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```